# Use Lagrange interpolation to prove $\max_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)|\leq\frac{(b-a)^2}{8}\max_{x\in[a,b]}|f''(x)|$

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

Suppose $f\in C^2([a,b])$ and $f(a)=f(b)=0$,use Lagrange interpolation to prove

$$\max_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)|\leq\frac{(b-a)^2}{8}\max_{x\in[a,b]}|f''(x)|$$

I tried to use the theoretic error to prove this but somehow things does not go very well and I don't see where I should use the condition $f(a)=f(b)=0$. Any hints for this?

Comment: Rolle's theorem states that f '(x)=0 for some x in [a,b], but i do not know if this helps.

Comment: For polynomials with degree 2, the statement is true : f(x)=c(x-a)(b-x)=c(-x^2+ax+bx-ab) has a maximum at $\frac{a+b}{2}$, which is $\frac{(b-a)^2}{4}$, which is $2\frac{(b-a)^2}{8}$.

Comment: I forgot the c at the last two expressions, sorry.

Comment: I guess a taylor series estimate brings the full solution.

Comment: @Peter Thank you, I will try this approach

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that the interpolating polynomial of degree $1$ that passes through $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$ is the zero polynomial.  Then use the remainder formula with $n=1$:
$$ R_n(x) = \frac{f^{n+1}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}(x-x_0)\cdots(x-x_n) $$
where $\xi$ lies between the minimum and maximum of $\{x,x_0,\dots,x_n\}$.

You can also use Taylor's series, but I think this is how you were meant to do the problem.